# metrics of function space - supermum and definite integral induce different topology?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Given $C[0,1]$ (continuous function space in $[0, 1]$),
Do supermum and definite integral as metrics induce a different topology?

Comment: Neither the supremum nor the definite integral are metrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the metrics $d(f,g)=\sup \{|f(x)-g(x)|: 0 \leq x \leq 1\}$ and $d'(f,g)=\int_0^{1} |f(x)-g(x)|\, dx$ then they are not equivalent: if $f_n(x)=1-nx$ for $ 0\leq x \leq \frac 1 n$ and $f_n(x)=0$ for $x >\frac 1 n$ then $f_n \to 0$ in the metric $d'$ but not in $d$.

Comment: Ok, there is a sequence of functions that converge to $f\left( x\right) =0$ in one topology but not in the other. And how can I deduce the inequality of topology further?

Comment: If the topologies are one and the same they  have same convergent sequences. Definition of convergence: $x_n \to x$ in a topological space if for every open set $U$ containing $x$ there exists $n_0$ such that $x_n \in U$ for all $n \geq n_0$.